# Does Krypto have a higher I.Q. than the average Earth human?

Tags: dc, superman

Does Superboy's superdog Krypto have a higher I.Q. than the average Earth human?

Comment: There are days when it appears an average Earth dog has a higher I.Q. than the average Earth human.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the "[Powers and Abilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krypto#Powers.2C_abilities.2C_and_equipment)" section of the wikipedia:

> In his **original, pre-Crisis incarnation**...He also had super-canine intelligence (**approximately human level, though with his canine traits and interests still present**); the comics expressed this via the use of thought balloons indicating what Krypto was thinking.
>
> In his **current incarnation**, Krypto's abilities are essentially identical; however, he **possesses normal canine intelligence**, though as shown in the storyline with Atlas, Krypto does seem to have a general understanding of speech, and can take initiatives of his own, such as vowing to protect Metropolis from Atlas because of his knowledge of the fact that Superman himself protects and cares for the city, as well as vowing to hurt Atlas for hurting Superman.

So it appears that originally he had approximately human level intelligence, but in his current "incarnation", he possesses normal canine intelligence.